Inequality for function on Spinor bundle
I have a function $H(x,\psi)$ defined on the spinor bundle $\mathbb{S}$ with $H_\psi$ being the continuous derivative in fiber direction having the following properties:
(H-1) There exists $0<\alpha<1$ such that $H$ is $\alpha$-Hölder continuous in the direction of the base. Moreover, there exist $2<p<\frac{2 m}{m-1}$ and $C_1>0$ such that
$$
\left|H_\psi(x, \psi)\right| \leq C_1\left(1+|\psi|^{p-1}\right)
$$
for any $(x, \psi) \in \mathbb{S}(M)$.
(H-2) There exist $\mu>2$ and $R_1>0$ such that
$$
0<\mu H(x, \psi) \leq\left\langle H_\psi(x, \psi), \psi\right\rangle
$$
for any $(x, \psi) \in \mathbb{S}(M)$ with $|\psi| \geq R_1$.
(H-3) $H(x, \psi) \geq 0$ for any $(x, \psi) \in \mathbb{S}(M)$.
(H-4) $H(x, \psi)=o\left(|\psi|^2\right)$ as $|\psi| \rightarrow 0$ uniformly for $x \in M$.
Then in a proof I am working on it says that the inequality $$H(x, \psi) \geq C_1|\psi|^\mu-C_2$$ for all $(x,\psi) \in \mathbb{S}$
follows from integrating the property (H-2). I have tried everything but I don't understand where the power of $\mu$ is supposed to come from when integrating. And even less how we should get a result for all $(x,\psi)$ when H-2 only holds for $\vert \psi(x) \vert \geq R_1$
I already tried multiple things. Using $H(x,0) = 0$ and integrating between 0 and 1 since integrating in $x$ seems not to yield anything.
Does anyone have an idea how to address this?
